# PHP Xpath - Parsing flat HTML structure

Tags: php, html, xpath

I am trying to parse some fairly flat HTML and group everything from one h1 tag to the next. For example, I have the following HTML:

```
<h1> Heading 1 </h1>
<p> Paragraph 1.1 </p>
<p> Paragraph 1.2 </p>
<p> Paragraph 1.3 </p>
<h1> Heading 2 </h1>
<p> Paragraph 2.1 </p>
<p> Paragraph 2.2 </p>
<h1> Heading 3 </h1>
<p> Paragraph 3.1 </p>
<p> Paragraph 3.2 </p>
<p> Paragraph 3.3 </p>
```

I basically want it to look like:

```
<div id='1'>
    <h1> Heading 1 </h1>
    <p> Paragraph 1.1 </p>
    <p> Paragraph 1.2 </p>
    <p> Paragraph 1.3 </p>
</div>
<div id='2'>
    <h1> Heading 2 </h1>
    <p> Paragraph 2.1 </p>
    <p> Paragraph 2.2 </p>
</div>
<div id='3'>
    <h1> Heading 3 </h1>
    <p> Paragraph 3.1 </p>
    <p> Paragraph 3.2 </p>
    <p> Paragraph 3.3 </p>
</div>
```

It is probably not even worth be posting the code I have done so far, as it just turned into a mess. Basically I was attempting to do an Xpath query for '//h1'. Create new DIV tags as parent nodes. Then copy the h1 DOM Node into the first DIV, and then loop over nextSibling until I hit another h1 tag - as mentioned it got messy.

Could someone point me in a better direction here?

Comment: I think your idea is good, but if you move elements, take care that this influences the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over all nodes that are on the same level (I created a hint node called platau in my example), whenever your run across `<h1>`, insert the div before and keep a reference to it.

For `<h1>` and any other node and if the reference exists, remove the node and add it as child to the reference.

Example:

```
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

$current = NULL;
$id = 0;
foreach($xp->query('/platau/node()') as $i => $sort)
{
    if (isset($sort->tagName) && $sort->tagName === 'h1')
    {
        $current = $doc->createElement('div');
        $current->setAttribute('id', ++$id);
        $current = $sort->parentNode->insertBefore($current, $sort);
    }
    if (!$current) continue;

    $sort->parentNode->removeChild($sort);
    $current->appendChild($sort);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/L8mXrReL)

Comment: Thank you hakre! That works perfectly! My code was no where near as efficient.

Comment: You're welcome. I got the idea mainly based on the description you gave in the question ;)